# Jquery Ajax Acting weird

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi I have been at this for days now and I just cant figure out why this isn't working, please could someone take a look.

index.php

```
<form id = "update_status" method = "POST">
                        <textarea id="shadow" name ="user_status" placeholder = "Share what is on your mind!" cols="97" rows="1" title="Share what's on your mind"></textarea>

                        <input style="float:right; margin-top: 0.3%;margin-right : 0% !important;" id = "btnStatus_update" name = "btnStatus_udate" type="button" value="Add Post" title="Your posts will be made public"></input></form>
```

swift.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#btnStatus_update").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert("Confirming function works");
        $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: './datacenter.php',
        data: $("#user_status"),
        success: function(d) {
            $("#successMesg").html(d);
        }
        });
    }); 
});
```

datacenter.php

```
if (isset($_POST['user_status'])) {
    var_dump($_POST['user_status']);
        foreach ($_POST as $ak => $av) {
            if (empty(trim($_POST['user_status']))) {
                echo 'Say what is on your mind'.' ';
            } else {
                $userstatus = $_POST['user_status'];
                add_user_status($user_data['id'], $userstatus);
            }
        }
    }
```

using var_dump for testing I was hoping it did return the data, but instead i get NULL, i need the data so i can pass it into the add_user_status function to be added to the database, but it seems there is something missing or off about the code denying me my satisfaction. Please help

Comment: you data propery is screwed up, you need to supply a key value pair for your php to work: `data: {user_status: $("#user_status").val()},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that appear to be missing:

Index.php:

You need to add an `action="something"` attribute to the form tag, this tells the form what to do when you submit it. (unless you are manually handling this is JS somewhere else?)

```
<form id = "update_status" action ="data.php" method = "POST">
```

Also, unless you are using JavaScript on the index page to handle the actual submitting of the form, your `<input>` should include a `type="submit"` attribute. (this will also make it a button) and when clicked it will automatically submit the form to the `action` location above.

Swift.php:

the code posted is JS, and does what the first line of the previous paragraph mentioned (handles the submit button). Do you include this file inside the `index.php`? if the `index.php` cannot see it, then it wont run. It must also be in the html somewhere in a proper `<script>` block.

I believe the correct way to send form data using ajax is to serialize the data:
`$('#update_status').serialize()` instead of just sending the one input field.

You will also be required to reference the jQuery libraries, preferably in the index, but could also go in swift.php. I am also assuming that the code posted appears in the necessary `<script>` block.

Data.php:

should this be `datacenter.php`? your `Swift.php` is sending the ajax request to `./datacenter.php`

On a side note, if you need it to use Ajax then you actually don't need the `action ="data.php" method = "POST"` in the form (Ajax does all that for you)

The way it could be done would be something like this:

Index.php:

```
// HTML beginning stuff
<head>
// Either reference the script in its own JS file or:
// Need to also include jquery library
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#btnStatus_update").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert("Confirming function works");
        $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: './datacenter.php',
        data: $('#update_status').serialize(),
        success: function(d) {
            $("#successMesg").html(d);
        }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id = "update_status">
<textarea id="shadow" name ="user_status" placeholder = "Share what is on your mind!" cols="97" rows="1" title="Share what's on your mind"></textarea>
<input style="float:right; margin-top: 0.3%;margin-right : 0% !important;" id = "btnStatus_update" name = "btnStatus_udate" type="button" value="Add Post" title="Your posts will be made public"></input>
</form>
</body>
```

datacenter.php:

```
<?php
var UserStatus = user_status
if (!empty(UserStatus)) {
    var_dump($_POST['user_status']);
// process as necessary
}

?>
```

But, including the 
`<form id = "update_status" action ="datacenter.php" method = "POST">` 
and changing the button to

`<input style="float:right; margin-top: 0.3%;margin-right : 0% !important;" id = "btnStatus_update" name = "btnStatus_udate" type="submit" value="Add Post" title="Your posts will be made public">`

will allow users to still post information if they have JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

the selector for the textarea is incorrect, the id is not "user_status", its "shadow"

```
data: $("#user_status"),
```

should really be:

```
data: $("textarea[name=user_status]")
```

or

```
data: $("#shadow")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I didn't take a try at this solution after the previous solution, I am sure this would have worked too